# SpeechRecognizer plays sound but delivers no results when calling startListening()

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I am trying to program a speech recognition without the dialog. For the first call of `SpeechRecognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent)`everything works fine and I get results with the recognised speech String. But when I want to start the recognition for the second time, only the recognition start sound is played and when I stop talking the recognition end sound. No callback methods like `onResults()`, `onRmsChanged`or `onError`etc. is called.

**The Activity:**

```
package com.example.plucinst.emojat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by thomasplucinski on 08/04/2017.
 */

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecognitionListener {

    private Button btnGoToChat;
    private ImageButton btnSpeechControl;
    private LinearLayout speechControlContainer;
    private Switch switchMode;
    private Activity context;
    private String firstMatchText;
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = null;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Intent recognizerIntent;
    private String messageText = "";
    private GlobalSetting globalSetting;
    private ArrayList<String> matchesText;
    private List<String> sendStringArray;
    private String recognizedContactName = "Gollum"; //For the prototyp the contact isn't recognized via speech but set as static value
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH = 1234;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_DETECTION = 0000;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "START_ACTIVITY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        globalSetting = GlobalSetting.getInstance();
        sendStringArray = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.send));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences_app_settings, false);
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        //

        initUI();

        // Init the speechRecognition
        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
        recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "de-DE");
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (globalSetting.speechRecognitionActive){
            startSpeechRecognition();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if device ist conntected to the internet
     * @return
     */
    public  boolean isConnected()
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo net = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (net!=null && net.isAvailable() && net.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the UI elements and the listeners
     */
    private void initUI(){
        btnGoToChat = (CustomButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_go_to_chat);
        btnSpeechControl = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_speech_control);
        switchMode = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_app_mode);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.speech_progress_bar);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        speechControlContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.speech_control_container);
        if (btnGoToChat!=null){
            btnGoToChat.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    goToInbox();

                }
            });
        }

        if (btnSpeechControl!=null){
            btnSpeechControl.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isConnected()){
                        startSpeechRecognition();
                        globalSetting.speechRecognitionActive = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Connect to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        globalSetting.speechRecognitionActive = false;
                    }
                    //goToInbox();

                }
            });
        }

        switchMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // do something, the isChecked will be
                // true if the switch is in the On position
                if (isChecked){
                    speechControlContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnGoToChat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    speechControlContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnGoToChat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void startSpeechRecognition(){


        /*
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH);
        */
        speechRecognizer.stopListening();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " call startSpeechRecognition");
        speechRecognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (speechRecognizer != null) {
            speechRecognizer.destroy();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setMax(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        //toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int errorCode) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
        //returnedText.setText(errorMessage);
        //toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        matchesText = results
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        processSpeechResults();

        //returnedText.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
        progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);
    }

    public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
        String message;
        switch (errorCode) {
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                message = "Audio recording error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
                message = "Client side error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
                message = "Insufficient permissions";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
                message = "Network error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                message = "Network timeout";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
                message = "No match";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
                message = "RecognitionService busy";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
                message = "error from server";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
                message = "No speech input";
                break;
            default:
                message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }

    private void processSpeechResults(){

        firstMatchText = matchesText.get(0); //because recognizerIntent returns a list of proposed matches to the recognized text and we only need the first
        Log.d("STARTACTIVITY", "recognized text: " + firstMatchText);

        //Do sth.
    }


}
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do not reuse the `Intent` instance, you must create a new one each time you start recognition.